# KnockoutJS Validation - Child validation rule OnlyIf based on parent viewModel field?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-validation

I'm using KnockoutJS on an ASP.NET application using the [knockout-validation](https://github.com/Knockout-Contrib/Knockout-Validation) extension.

I have parent and child viewModels. I need one of the fields in the child viewModel to only be required when a field in the parent viewModel has a value of X.

This is what I currently have, but this doesn't work:

```
ko.validation.init({
    registerExtenders: true,
    messagesOnModified: true,
    insertMessages: true,
    parseInputAttributes: false,
    decorateElemen: true,
    messageTemplate: null,
    grouping: {
        deep: true,
        live: true,
        observable: true
    }
});

var childVM = function (data, selected, parent) {
    var self = this;

    self.parent = ko.observable(parent);

    self.ChildField = ko.observable();

    self.isSelected = ko.computed(function () {
        return self === selected();
    }, self);

    // validation
    self.validationObject = ko.validatedObservable({
        ChildField: self.ChildField.extend({
            required: {
                onlyIf: function () {
                    console.log(self.parent().ParentField());
                    return self.parent().ParentField() == 2;
                }
            }
        }),
    });
}

var ParentVM = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);

    self.ParentField = ko.observable();

    self.children = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.children.push(new ChildVM({ }, self.selectedTab, self));

    // Validation
    self.validationObject = ko.validatedObservable({
        Children: self.children
    });

    self.save = function () {
        if ( self.errors().length === 0 ) {
            self.errors.showAllMessages(false);
        } else {
            self.errors.showAllMessages();
            return false;
        };


        var raw = ko.mapping.toJS(self, mapping);
        return $.ajax({
            // foo
        });
    }
}
```

The console log outputs the value when the viewModels are initialised, not when the save function is executed and the validation runs?

Comment: creating a fiddle would be helpful

Comment: We need to be able to run the code ourselves to solve the problem. Either provide the relevant html as well, or as gkb said, a fiddle (much better option).

Comment: btw I don't see self.errors defined anywhere.

Comment: The errors collection will be provided by knockout.validation, but will exist on the validationObject not the root viewmodel...  It should be `self.validationObject.errors`...